# Lines and Borders disappear when position:fixed. CSS and Google Chrome Issue?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am trying to create a horizontal position:fixed line at the top of my website. The layout is two vertical columns. One the left is a fixed menu bar, the right is scrolling content. The horizontal fixed line goes across the top of the scrolling content.

I have created a vertical line dividing these columns like so:

HTML:

```
<div id="vline"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#vline {
    min-width: 1px;         /* thickness of line */
    width: 1px;         /* thickness of line */
    height: 300px;          /* length of line (down) */
    background-color: #959595;  /* Line color */
    margin-left: 205px;     /* locating on page */
    position: fixed;        /* fix to window */
    }
```

However, when I add position:fixed to the horizontal line, it just disappears. Obviously leaving it in normal flow or trying to position it by any other means (absolute or relative) causes it to scroll with the rest of the scrolling content. I thought it might be a problem with the line so I have also tried defining a border as shown:

HTML:

```
<div id="hline"></div>
```

CSS:

```
    #hline {
    border-top: 1px solid #959595;
    width: auto;            /* width match window size */
    margin-left: 205px;     /* locating on page */
    margin-bottom: 5px;     /* offset for text content bellow */
    position: fixed;
}
```

This has the same problem as using a line. It works fine, the line appears where I want it, at the top of the scrolling column, but until I add position:fixed it will of course scroll with the content. As soon as I do add position:fixed, it disappears.

Unless I am doing something obviously wrong or there is another way to position it I haven't tried, the only thing I can think of is that it is a browser rendering bug. I am using the latest version of Google Chrome.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Position the bars using top and left.
For example,

```
 #hline, #vline{top: 0; left: 0;}
```

That should do it. You might have a few minor width problems. I suggest doing everything with % instead of hard-coding px.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but it still scrolls with the content. I guess I am misunderstanding how to use the solution, sorry!

Comment: Make sure you use position: fixed. Do you have an online demo for this like on jsFiddle?